If $\mathrm{rank}\left(AB\right)=\mathrm{rank}\left(B\right)$, would $\mathrm{rank}\left(AB^2\right)=\mathrm{rank}\left(B^2\right)$?
Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ complex matrices. If $\mathrm{rank}\left(AB\right)=\mathrm{rank}\left(B\right)$, would $\mathrm{rank}\left(AB^2\right)=\mathrm{rank}\left(B^2\right)$?
I think $A$ may be injective on $\mathrm{Im}\left(B\right)$. Is that true?

Use latex, and show your efforts on solving the question.

Did you try some examples where both A and B have rank strictly less than n?

What do you mean by "$A$ may be interval on $\mathrm{Im}\left(B\right)$"?
If you meant injective, you are right. This is the key idea. Prove that $$\mathrm{rank}\left(AB\right)=\mathrm{rank}\left(B\right)\iff A\text{ is injective on }\mathrm{Im}\left(B\right)$$ (hence same when $B$ is replaced everywhere by $B^2$), and you are done! (since $\mathrm{Im}\left(B^2\right)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}\left(B\right)$)

@Afntu I didn't roll back from your edit but I think that 淘宝者 should have done these two modifications themself (or at least indicated them in comments), otherwise we cannot be completely sure that is what they meant.

Yes, you are correct, but I thought OP meant injective, so I edited that.

I hope it is clear to you that $\mathrm{Im}(T) = \{T(v): v \in V\}$ is a subspace of $V$, where $T: V \to V$ is a linear transformation from a vector space to the same vector space. And if $A$ is a matrix, then you can consider it as a linear transformation and $\dim(\mathrm{Im}(A)) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$.
Consider $A, B$, a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ to $V$.
Now it is very easy to observe that $\mathrm{Im}(B^{2}) \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(B)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(AB^{2}) \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(AB)$. As $\mathrm{Im}(B), \mathrm{Im}(AB)$ are spaces of $V$, we can define a restricted linear transformation $A: \mathrm{Im}(B) \to \mathrm{Im}(AB)$.
Which is a subjective map. Also, it is given that $\mathrm{rank}(AB) = \mathrm{rank}(B)$, so by rank nullity theorem $\dim(\mathrm{Im}(AB)) + \dim(\ker(A|_{\mathrm{Im}(B)})) = dim(\mathrm{Im}(B)) \implies \dim(\ker(A|_{\mathrm{Im}(B)})) = 0$, which implies $\ker(A) \cap \mathrm{Im}(B) = \{0\}$.
Since $\mathrm{Im}(B^{2}) \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(B)$ so $\ker(A) \cap \mathrm{Im}(B^{2}) = \{0\} \implies \ker(A|_{\mathrm{Im}(B^{2})}) = \{0\}$.
Now, from the above discussion, we can say that $A: \mathrm{Im}(B^{2}) \to \mathrm{Im}(AB^{2})$ is an injective map, and it is also a surjective map; hence it is an isomorphism.
So $\mathrm{rank}(AB^{2}) = \mathrm{rank}(B^{2})$.

What is a "subjective" map?

Sorry, it is surjective. I will edit that. It was a mistake. Thanks for pointing out :-)

Your intuition was good (up to the lapsus "interval" for "injective"). Let us first prove the following key lemma:
$$\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(B)\iff A\text{ is injective on }\operatorname{Im}(B).$$
Let $(b_1,\dots,b_r)$ be a basis of $\operatorname{Im}(B)$. Then, its its image $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ under $A$ spans $\operatorname{Im}(AB)$, whose dimension is therefore equal to $r$ iff $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ is linearly independent, i.e. iff $\sum\lambda_ia_i=0\implies\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_r=0$. This condition rewrites $A(\sum\lambda_ib_i)=0\implies\sum\lambda_ib_i=0$, i.e. $A$ is injective on $\operatorname{Im}(B)$. This ends the proof of the lemma.
From this lemma (which holds for any $B$ hence also for $B^2$), we derive:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(B)&\implies A\text{ is injective on }\operatorname{Im}(B)\\&\implies A\text{ is injective on the subspace }\operatorname{Im}(B^2)\\&\implies\operatorname{rank}(AB^2)=\operatorname{rank}(B^2).\end{align}$$
